# JQuery : Sending multiple files and parameters got Error: Dropzone already attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to send multiple files together of of value from input fields using dropzone. Unfortunately I got an error says dropzone already attached.

Here is my code

```
 $(document).on('click','#addContestant',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var random_gender = $('#randomGender').val();
    var contestant_name = $('#contestant_name').val();
    var contestant_lastName = $('#contestant_lastName').val();
    var conAge = $('#conAge').val();
    var hAddress = $('#hAddress').val();
    var email_add = $('#email_add').val();
    var conContactNum = $('#conContactNum').val();
    var conDesc = $('#conDesc').val();
    var hidden_gender = $('#hidden_gender').val();
    var conId_hidden = $('#conId_hidden').val(); // the contestant prima id

    var param = "?event_id="+encodeURIComponent(event_id)+
                "&contestant_name="+encodeURIComponent(contestant_name)+
                "&contestant_lastName="+encodeURIComponent(contestant_lastName)+
                "&conAge="+encodeURIComponent(conAge)+
                "&hAddress="+encodeURIComponent(hAddress)+
                "&email_add="+encodeURIComponent(email_add)+
                "&conContactNum="+encodeURIComponent(conContactNum)+
                "&conDesc="+encodeURIComponent(conDesc)+
                "&conId_hidden="+encodeURIComponent(conId_hidden)+
                "&hidden_gender="+encodeURIComponent(hidden_gender)+
                "&random_gender="+encodeURIComponent(random_gender)+
                "&multipleImage="+encodeURIComponent(multipleImage);

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('form#my-awesome-dropzone', {
        url : '../ajax/ajax_add/ajax_addNEWContestant.php?'+param,
        maxFilesize: 3.0, 
        maxFiles: 4,
        parallelUploads: 10000,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });

  });
```

Comment: You are adding Dropzone to the form element inside a click event, which means every time the item is clicked, this code runs. Which gives you the error message every time you click it beyond the first time, since, as it says, Dropzone has already been added to the target element. You have to either a) add dropzone to the form on `domready`  instead of on click, or b) if you are dynamically adding a new field elsewhere in your code, only add it to the field itself, not the form.

Comment: If i use the a. My input field values will not send. Only the files from dropzone, how can i implement files and input fields value same together.

Comment: You can use a `<form>` including `<input type="file" multiple>` element with `multiple` attribute set. User can drop a selection of multiple files at `<input type="file" multiple>` element, then user can submit form which should include both files and other input fields within `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Baker is right, here you going to attach multiple Dropzone on same element, who will fails.

Try to init dropzone once and use event 'sending'.

```
// Dropzone config
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// To run when dom is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Manual Dropzone init
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('form#my-awesome-dropzone', {
        url : '../ajax/ajax_add/ajax_addNEWContestant.php',
        maxFilesize: 3.0,
        ...
    });

    // Add dynamic event on sending
    myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
        // Fetch values to send
        var contestant_name = $('#contestant_name').val();
        ...

        // Add it to request data send by Dropzone
        formData.append('event_id', encodeURIComponent(event_id));
        formData.append('contestant_name', encodeURIComponent(contestant_name));
        ...
    });

});
```

or directly in initialisation

```
// Dropzone config
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// To run when dom is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Manual Dropzone init
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('form#my-awesome-dropzone', {
        url : '../ajax/ajax_add/ajax_addNEWContestant.php',
        maxFilesize: 3.0,
        ...
        sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
            // Fetch values to send
            var contestant_name = $('#contestant_name').val();
            ...

            // Add it to request data send by Dropzone
            formData.append('event_id', encodeURIComponent(event_id));
            formData.append('contestant_name', encodeURIComponent(contestant_name));
            ...
        }

    });

});
```